MATLAB fmincon with non linear constraints
I need to minimize the fisher information determinant in order to get some optimized yaw rates the the AUV model to follow an optimal path.
The minimization function contains some non linear constraints and the fmincon function return the optimal yaw rate and optimal speed for a particular iteration. I don't know how to define the nonlcon constraints function as it has to take certain parameters that are not returned by the fmincon function but are available from some other matlab file.
(https://i.sstatic.net/0y9uw.png)
(https://i.sstatic.net/iGf28.png)
This is the MATLAB code I've written
% Given parameters
function [optimized_yaw_rates, optimized_speed, max_objective_value] = target_optimize(x_k1, x0, yaw, x_tilde, x_nominal, distances, psi0, v0, m, sigma, target)
    % Adjust as needed
    %     m = length(x_tilde);  % Assuming u_rates is the vector of yaw rates obtained
    % Define equality constraint: p(k+1) = p(k) + sum(u(i))

    % Objective function (negative since fmincon minimizes)
    objective = @(uv) -detFIMCostFunction(uv(1), uv(2), sigma);
    rb = pi/9;

    % Constraints (if any, e.g., bounds on yaw rates)
    lb = [-rb, 0];  % Lower bounds for [u, v]
    ub = [rb, 1.5];  % Upper bounds for [u, v]

    % Initial guess (you can use the obtained yaw rates as the starting point)
    initial_guess = [psi0, v0];  % Initial guess for [u, v]
    % Initialize max_objective_value
    max_objective_value = -Inf;
    % Call fmincon
    options = optimoptions(@fmincon, ...
        'MaxFunctionEvaluations', 1e6, ...
        'MaxIterations', 1e6, ...
        'TolX', 1e-6, ...
        'TolFun', 1e-6, ...
        'Algorithm', 'interior-point', ...
        'StepTolerance', 1e-6, ...
        'ConstraintTolerance', 1e-6);

    [optimized_params, max_objective_value] = fmincon(objective, initial_guess, [], [], [],[], lb, ub, @nonlcon, options);
    optimized_yaw_rates = optimized_params(1);
    optimized_speed = optimized_params(2);
    disp('Optimized Yaw Rates:');
    disp(optimized_yaw_rates);
    disp('Maximum Objective Value:');
    disp(-max_objective_value);  % Note the negative sign here

    % Define the nonlinear constraint function for fmincon
    function [c, ceq] = nonlcon(x_k1,x0,yaw)
        p0 = x0(1:2);
        psi0 = x0(3);
        p_k1 = x_k1(1:2);
        psi_k1 = x_k1(3);
        ceq(1) =  p_k1 - p0 - 1.5*[cos(psi_k1); sin(psi_k1)];
        ceq(2) = psi_k1 - psi0 - sum(yaw);
        c = [];  % Compute nonlinear inequalities.
    end

    % Define the cost function for |FIMp|^2
    function cost = detFIMCostFunction(u, v, sigma)
        x_tilde_func = matlabFunction(x_tilde);
        distances_func = matlabFunction(distances);
        fim = [0, 0; 0, 0];
        P0 = [1, 0; 0, 1];
        x_tilde_numeric = x_tilde_func(u, v);
        distances_numeric = distances_func(u, v);
        for i = 1:m
            fim = fim + 1/(distances_numeric(i)^2) * [x_tilde_numeric(1, i)^2, x_tilde_numeric(1, i)*x_tilde_numeric(2, i); x_tilde_numeric(1, i)*x_tilde_numeric(2, i), x_tilde_numeric(2, i)^2];
        end
        cost = log((1/sigma^2)*det(fim + inv(P0)));
    end
end


I tried to write a nonlinear constraint function with parameters but got an error saying not enough input arguments when I put it in fmincon(..,..,.. nonlcon,..) function.

The error is because when fmincon calls nonlcon, it only passes the current x vector it's looking at. When plugging the nonlinear function in fmincon, you have to fix the remaining arguments. Assuming x_k1 is the variable being optimized, you can modify your fmincon call as follows
[optimized_params, max_objective_value] = fmincon(objective, initial_guess, [], [], [],[], lb, ub, @(x) nonlcon(x,x0,yaw), options);


Thanks, I'll try this . But my Fmincon returns only two values as optimized params velocity and yaw rate, while in this nonllinear constraint I have to use the previous values of yaw rates as well, so should i change the nonlinear constraints equation , that's what is confusing me.
